# Airflow: PostgresOperator loading sql file fails due to jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Tags: python, sql, airflow, jinja2

I know this is an issue that keeps coming up a lot but I have read many solutions and none of them seems to solve my issue. I'm trying to execute a SQL query using **PostgreOperator** and a .sql file file named **delete.sql**. I have a git repository named **external_datasources** which contains several dags that are all accessible through Airflow. My Airflow instance is deployed using Docker and the dags folder is mounted to the container.

I'm currently trying to run the aforementioned dag of file dag_that_runs_delete_query.py that executes query from delete.sql file. But I keep getting the **jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: delete.sql** error.

The file structure of external_datasources repository is the following. While the full path to the repository is **/home/etl/airflow-docker/dags/external_datasources**

```
.
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── conf.py
├── dw
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── queries
│   │   ├── delete.sql
│   │   ├── query1.sql
│   │   └── query2.sql
│   └── dag_that_runs_delete_query.py
├── helper_for_dag1.py
├── helper_for_dag2.py
├── dag1.py
├── dag2.py
├── dag3.py
├── requirements.txt
└── utils.py
```

My dag looks like this, I'm using the template_searchpath as many have suggested

```py
dag = DAG(
    'dag_that_runs_delete_query',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A DAG that runs a sql query',
    schedule='0 4 * * *',
    catchup=False,
    template_searchpath="/home/etl/airflow-docker/dags/external_datasources/dw/queries"
)

with dag:
    delete_before_insert_task = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='delete_before_insert',
        postgres_conn_id='connection_for_postgres',
        sql="delete.sql",
        params={
            "table_name": "test_table",
            "destination_table_schema": "dw"
        }
    )

    delete_before_insert_task
```

The SQL file looks like this

```sql
DELETE FROM {{ destination_table_schema }}.{{ table_name }}
WHERE created_on >= {{ ts }}
AND created_on < {{ ts }} + INTERVAL '{{ schedule_interval }}'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

schedule_interval is not a valid macro - you can see [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/macros.html) the available macros.

schedule_interval is a property of the DAG.

try to pass {{ dag.schedule_interval }}

also the problem can be related to the template_searchpath, try to add "/" to sql path "/delete.sql" or absolute path just to be sure that this is the issue here (except validation of the sql itself). see this [post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822380/templatenotfound-when-using-airflows-postgresoperator-with-jinja-templating-and)

```
DELETE FROM {{ params.destination_table_schema }}.{{ params.table_name }}
WHERE created_on >= {{ ts }}
AND created_on < {{ ts }} + INTERVAL '{{ dags.schedule_interval }}'
```

Comment: Hello @ozs your point is indeed right I was planning to pass it as a constant in the params dictionary though. Are you sure it is going to work like that, without passing the dag.schedule_interval in the params dict?
Any way this doesn't solve my initial error as the template is not found at all.

Comment: I looked at airflow docs again, I thinks you are missing the params prefix before each param in the sql I updated my answer). about the dags.schedule_interval its like the {{ ts }} macro.

Comment: I also so some posts about the template_search that this issue might be related

Comment: You are right about the "params." prefix but it seems to not solve the TemplateNotFound error, I have also removed the  + INTERVAL '{{ dags.schedule_interval }}' part at this stage just to be more sure about the thing that I try but the error persists

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822380/templatenotfound-when-using-airflows-postgresoperator-with-jinja-templating-and about the template_search. it has similar issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by using a relative path from the specific dag I wanted to run to the sql file, without using template_searchpath at all.

```
dag = DAG(
    'dag_that_runs_delete_query',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A DAG that runs a sql query',
    schedule='0 4 * * *',
    catchup=False
)

with dag:
    delete_before_insert_task = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='delete_before_insert',
        postgres_conn_id='connection_for_postgres',
        sql="queries/delete.sql",
        params={
            "table_name": "test_table",
            "destination_table_schema": "dw"
        }
    )

    delete_before_insert_task
```